# How to append a table in PDF using iTextsharp without knowing the exact number of pages the table will produce

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012, itext, pdfptable

I'm using iTextSharp to create a PDF and I'm creating multiple tables that run inline in my code. I won't know how long the table is going to be when I fill it with values from my collection. And I don't want one table to run into or through the next. This is what I have so far, but if the table runs into the next page, it overlaps the table that I placed in the next line of code with a page break -NewPage()-

```
// Page 1 Searches 
            doc.NewPage();

            cb.BeginText();
            centerText(cb, "HeaderText for Searches", 300, 760, _fontbold, 18);
            cb.EndText();

            PdfPTable tableSearches = new PdfPTable(4);
            PdfPCell cellSearches = new PdfPCell();

            cellSearches.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;

            cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase("Company");
            tableSearches.AddCell(cellLKQ);
            cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase("Contact");
            tableSearches.AddCell(cellLKQ);
            cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase("Phone Number");
            tableSearches.AddCell(cellLKQ);
            cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase("Amount");
            tableSearches.AddCell(cellLKQ);

            //loop through the records in facilities collection and add row
            foreach (var m in facilities)
            {
                cellSearches.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;

                cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Facility);
                tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);

                cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase(m.FacilityContact);
                tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);

                cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Phone);
                tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);

                cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase(m.SalvageQuote.ToString());
                tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);
            }

            doc.Add(tableSearches);

            //Page 2? AM Searches

            doc.NewPage();

            cb.BeginText();
            centerText(cb, "HeaderText AM Searches", 300, 760, _fontbold, 18);
            cb.EndText();

            PdfPTable tableAM = new PdfPTable(4);
            PdfPCell cellAM = new PdfPCell();

            cellAM.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;

            cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase("Company");
            tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);
            cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase("Contact");
            tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);
            cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase("Phone Number");
            tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);
            cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase("Amount");
            tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);

            //loop through the records and add row
            foreach (var m in amfacilities)
            {
                cellAM.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.CYAN;
                cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Facility);
                tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);

                cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase(m.FacilityContact);
                tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);

                cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Phone);
                tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);

                cellLKQ.Phrase = new Phrase(m.SalvageQuote.ToString());
                tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);
            }

            doc.Add(tableAM);

            //Page 3? Another Table
              doc.NewPage();
           // Code for next table
```

Comment: Does it overlap the table or the header? You're mixing iTextSharp's abstractions like `Document.Add()` and `PdfPTables` with raw PDF commands like `PdfContentByte.BeginText()` which is prone to breaking. The abstractions take care of flowing everything freely but the moment you write manual PDF commands all bets are off.

Comment: Chris Haas is correct. Also: if you want a good answer, you'll have to clarify. What should the end result look like? Right now, your question looks like you didn't read much of the documentation.

Comment: My apologies. What I have is a whole bunch of tables that I'm creating. And I don't want data from one table to run into data from the table following it. Also a new table will start at the top of a new page every time. It actually works correctly doing it this way, I just didn't know if there was a better way of creating that separation. Chris you are correct. Thanks for the suggestions as well. I don't usually post to forums, but when I do, I prefer stackoverflow. This is solved now because it actually works doing it this way. Table - PageBreak - Table - PageBreak etc.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the advice, you've been my go to guy for questions regarding iTextSharp throughout my entire project! While you may or may not even know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removed contentbyte and added a new paragraph to the document. Quite simply this solved what I needed to achive: A table with a Title header, new table starting on a new page.

```
        doc.Open();

        doc.Add(new Paragraph(new Chunk("Header for Searches" + Chunk.NEWLINE + Chunk.NEWLINE, fb)));

        PdfPTable tableSearches = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cellSearches = new PdfPCell();

        cellSearches.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;

        cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase("Facility ID");
        tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);
        cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase("Facility");
        tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);
        cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase("Phone Number");
        tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);

        //loop through the records in facilities collection and add row
        foreach (var m in facilityList)
        {
            cellSearches.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;

            cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Id.ToString());
            tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);

            cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Facility);
            tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);

            cellSearches.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Phone);
            tableSearches.AddCell(cellSearches);
        }

        doc.Add(tableSearches);

        //Page 2? AM Searches

        doc.NewPage();

        doc.Add(new Paragraph(new Chunk("Header for AM Searches" + Chunk.NEWLINE + Chunk.NEWLINE, fb)));

        PdfPTable tableAM = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cellAM = new PdfPCell();

        cellAM.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;

        cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase("Facility ID");
        tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);
        cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase("Facility");
        tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);
        cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase("Phone Number");
        tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);

        //loop through the records and add row
        foreach (var m in facilityList)
        {
            cellAM.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.CYAN;
            cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Id.ToString());
            tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);

            cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Facility);
            tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);

            cellAM.Phrase = new Phrase(m.Phone);
            tableAM.AddCell(cellAM);
        }

        doc.Add(tableAM);

        doc.Close();
```

[image]